# how to assign ID and value for UIpicker rows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uipickerview

Here's the scenario I am populating a UIPicker using JSON.

here's my JSON

```
{"id":["232","432"],"contact":["Administrator","Main"]}
```

I stored the data into an NSdictionary , then after converting to the object, I created an NSarray to store the contact.

I am able to display the `contact` value to the dropdown using NSJSONserialization.

I would like to send in my JSON post request the corresponding `id` of the contact selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're populating your data source incorrectly. You should have a model like this:

contacts : [ { id : "12", name : "Administrator" }, { id : "13", name : "Dude" } ]

After you parse it into the array, in the `-pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` you'll have to pick an NSDictionary value from. Grab the id value from the dictionary fetched from your data source from the `-pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` method.

edit

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  NSNumber *idNumber = _contacts[row][@"id"];
  //perform whatever action you need to with selected contact id
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have adjusted my JSON , but I don't understand what you mean by grab `Grab the id value from the dictionary fetched from your data source ` please elaborate a lil bit more thanks.

Comment: made a brief edit, you should be able to understand what I meant now

Answer (score -1):

try setting the id to the UIPicker using a tag like so,

picker.tag = 232;